# Why .gitignore not working for the new project in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, gitignore

I created project in Android Studio with .gitignore file.

```
.DS_Store

# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
out/
gen/

# Libraries used by the app
# Can explicitly add if we want, but shouldn't do so blindly.  Licenses, bloat, etc.
/libs


# Build stuff (auto-generated by android update project ...)
build.xml
ant.properties
local.properties
project.properties

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project

# idea project files
.idea/
.idea/.name
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws

##Gradle-based build
.gradle
build/
```

After this I used `git init` command in project directory.
[image: git init screenshot]

`git status` command
[image: git status screenshot]

`git add .` and `git status` commands
[image: git add screenshot]

`git commit` command
[image: git commit screenshot]

`git status` command with empty value
[image: git status screenshot]

Version of Git is 1.9.1. I don't understand why those files added to commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, this is a bug in 1.9.1 version.

You should update git.

[Git v2.0 Release Notes](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt)

> Updates since v1.9 series
>
> - Trailing whitespaces in .gitignore files, unless they are quoted
>   for fnmatch(3), e.g. "path\ ", are warned and ignored. Strictly
>   speaking, this is a backward-incompatible change, but very unlikely
>   to bite any sane user and adjusting should be obvious and easy.

[Git v2.1 Release Notes](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.1.0.txt)

> Fixes since v2.0
>
> - Mishandling of patterns in .gitignore that have trailing SPs quoted
>   with backslashes (e.g. ones that end with "\ ") has been
>   corrected.
>   (merge 97c1364be6b pb/trim-trailing-spaces later to maint).

[Git 2.5 Release Notes](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.5.0.txt)

> Fixes since v2.4
>
> - The codepaths that read .gitignore and .gitattributes files have been
>   taught that these files encoded in UTF-8 may have UTF-8 BOM marker at
>   the beginning; this makes it in line with what we do for configuration
>   files already.
>   (merge 27547e5 cn/bom-in-gitignore later to maint).